# does bash $0 start a background process?

Tags: bash

I know `echo $0` return what shell I am in but when I run just `$0` in terminal it return nothing and when I try to close the terminal it says there is still a program running in the terminal. I also tried running `$1 $2` in the terminal and it didn't prompt me when closing. Does running `$0` in terminal starts a background process or am I missing something?

Comment: A word of advice: Avoid closing the terminal by clicking the close button. Exit all the shells running in the tabs (ctrl+D). When the last tab closes, the terminal window closes with it.

Answer (score 2):

> I know `echo $0` return what shell I am in but when I run just `$0` in terminal it return nothing.

As `$0` contains the shell command that is running your shell script or interactive session; when you type `$0` in a terminal, you are invoking the command name within the `$0` argument variable.

When `$0` contains `bash`; Typing `$0` in the terminal, just runs `bash`.  It then runs another bash within the scope of the first one, as a sub-shell.

As it runs another shell, it look like it did nothing, but started another shell session with same environment variables and settings. The shell prompt and current directory are exactly the same, so it look like nothing happened.

If you then try to close the terminal window, while a sub-shell has been invoked, it will tell you there are still background processes running.

What happens when you close the terminal window, is: It signals the first higher level shell `P`rocess `ID` to terminate, but this shell's `PID` know it has some child `PID` still attached, and just tells you about it.